# Eiffel: Do expanded types conform to ANY?

Tags: types, polymorphism, eiffel

1. Assume that `foo: ANY` is an assignable entity.
2. What happens when I do `foo := create {BOOLEAN}`?

It would fail always, because `BOOLEAN` (an expanded type) does not conform to `ANY` (a reference type), correct?

Comment: I was in the impression that every type, expanded or not, is conform to ANY. I test that code:
    foo := create {BOOLEAN}
and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanded types conform to reference ones (provided that other conformance requirements are satisfied). So, the example you mention works just fine. Moreover, it is ok to write `foo := True`.

The key difference after such reattachments is that copy semantics of expanded types is preserved, i.e. if there is an entity `bar` of type `ANY`, the assignment `bar := foo` will attach a copy of the boolean object to `bar`, not the same reference. So, if a value of the object attached to `foo` is changed afterwards, `bar` remains unchanged.

Answering your original question, `BOOLEAN` conforms to `ANY`.

Comment: Then if `foo: INTEGER_8_REF`, am I allowed to do `foo := create {INTEGER_8}`?

Comment: @g4v3, yes, this should be fine. BTW, if the answer is satisfactory, you can mark it as accepted so that SO users can see that the question is answered. Otherwise, you are welcome to request for more details.

Comment: Yes, that is essentially the reason why I hadn't marked it as accepted earlier on. I was still not finished with your answer. I wanted to ask one more thing. But I was also pondering if I should post it as a comment, or as a question of its own. I've decided on posting it as an independent question. I'll be waiting for your answer then!  :)